# Bootstrap form inline not center with validation message

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help with form inline in Bootstrap.

I want to have all inputs of same height (or centered), but problem is when I have a validation message.
DEMO:
http://codepen.io/Tursky/pen/gpvgBL?editors=100

And also have this message under Input

Thanks for your help

```
<form class="col-xs-12">
<div class="form-inline row"  style="padding:25px;">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
        <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" >ERROR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
        <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" ></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
        <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" ></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
        <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" ></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not assign `id`s multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill that space with `&nbsp;` (shortcut for new blank space).

Working example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPQKXG).

```
<form class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-inline row"  style="padding:25px;">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
            <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" >ERROR</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
            <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" >&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
            <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" >&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label" for="playerId">*Player ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control player-input" id="playerId" name="playerId">
            <span id="playerIdError" class="help-block" >&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```